# Create duplicate row for each item in column containing delimited string

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table with a column that stores time blocks separated by semi-colons (`;`). I would like to create a row for each time block, for example, given

[image]

I'd like to create a row for each time block

[image]

Please let me know if this possible in Access.

## Edit

I tried using this query

```sql
SELECT * INTO ImportedData
FROM (
  SELECT [SourceData].[Time block], [SourceData].[Work History Id],[SourceData].[Operation Code]
  FROM SourceData
  WHERE InStr([SourceData].[Time block], ';') = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Left([SourceData].[Time block], InStr([SourceData].[Time block], ';') - 1),[SourceData].[Work History Id], [SourceData].[Operation Code]
  FROM SourceData
  WHERE InStr([SourceData].[Time block], ';') > 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Mid([SourceData].[Time block], InStr([SourceData].[Time block], ';') + 1), [SourceData].[Work History Id], [SourceData].[Operation Code]
  FROM SourceData
  WHERE InStr([SourceData].[Time block], ';') > 0) AS CleanedUp;
```

and I also tried this VBA code with no luck.

```vbs
Public Sub addToTable()
    Dim rstObj As DAO.Recordset, dbObj As DAO.Database
    Dim InsertSQL As String
    Set dbObj = CurrentDb()
    Set rstObj = dbObj.OpenRecordset("Query1")
    Do While Not rstObj.EOF
        Dim memArr() As String
        memArr = Split(rstObj.Fields("Time block"), ",")
        For i = 0 To UBound(memArr)
            InsertSQL = "SELECT*INTO ImportedData(Time block, Work History ID) VALUES(""" & rstObj.Fields("Time block") & """, """ & memArr(i) & """)"
            DoCmd.RunSQL (InsertSQL)
        Next
        rstObj.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: why was this question marked down ?

Comment: "why was this question marked down ?" - Possibly because you have asked an "Is it possible?" question without giving any indication of what you have researched or what you have tried yourself. Have a look at [this answer on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269359/2144390).

Comment: I apologize for oversight, i have tried different approached via query and so far this is the only one that somewhat work ok, the sql provided does not work correctly because it inserts blank records or sometimes does not split the string correctly, any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here [enter link description here][1]

[1]: http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=239727 for anyone that may b have the same requirements, i would hope people would actually help instead of just marking down answers or correcting the way the question is asked.